Show that there are countable many formulas $\phi (y)$ of one free variable $y$ in the formal language.
This is Exercise $6.43$ from Goldrei's Classic Set Theory.
For this exercise, it is possible to avoid use of AC.
We can take the variable symbols for sets in our formal language for set theory, as in Chapter $4$, as those in the countable set $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\}$. Thus formulas are built up from these variables, brackets and the symbols $\in, =, \neg, \land, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow, \forall, \exists$.
Show that there are countable many formulas $\phi (y)$ of one free variable $y$ in the formal language. (This shows that the axiom of separation can be used to describe at most countably many subsets of an infinite set $x$, where Cantor's theorem says that such an $x$ has uncountably many subsets. Our inability to describe all of the subsets of $x$ in a finite way is of course an important of both set theory and of us!)
Note that this is the definition of free variable $y$ in the textbook which is slightly more restricted than the definition in any standard treatment of predicate calculus:
The variable $v$ occuring in a formula $\phi$ is described as a free variable of $\phi$ if no stage of the building up of $\phi$ has involved putting $\forall v$ or $\exists v$ in front of a statement in which $v$ appears.
My attempt:
Since AC isn't allowed, the remaining techniques that I know of is to construct a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and the set $X$ of formulas $\phi (y)$ of one free variable $y$ in the formal language, use Schröder–Bernstein theorem or use axiom of dependent choice. I have no idea on how to use any of the techniques other than using Schröder–Bernstein theorem for this problem. I defined a function $f: \Bbb N\rightarrow X$ by $f(n)= (x_n=x_n)$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$. Since $f$ is one-one, we have $\Bbb N \prec X$.
I have no idea how to construct a one-to-one function from $X$ to $\Bbb N$.
As a side note, I am not certain if $X$ is a set or not within $ZF$.

Hint: Every formula is represented by a finite sequence of symbols. Try to show that the set of finite sequences of symbols (ranging over a finite set, i.e., the set of words $Σ^*$ on an alphabet $Σ$) is countable.

Would this work? Each formula is a finite word over the alphabet Σ=${\in, =, \neg, \land, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow, \forall, \exists,(,),x,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$. We may encode them using a bijection $s$ that maps them to $0,1,2,...,21$ respectively. Given a formula $a_1a_2...a_m$, define a $g$ by mapping $a_1a_2...a_m$ to $s(a_1)22^{m-1}+s(a_2)22^{m-2}+\cdots +s(a_{m-1})22+s(a_m)$. $g$ is one-to-one so we have $X \prec \Bbb N$. I don't think $g$ is bijective since formula can't end in the symbols $\in, =, \neg, \land, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow, \forall, \exists,($.

No, it's not a bijection. But instead of a searching for a bijection explicitly, it's much simpler to only show that the set of formulas is at most countable (which means there is an injection from it into ℕ, and since it's obviously infinite, i.e. there's an injection from ℕ into it, you get a bijection by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein). The set of formulas injects into $Σ^$ (each formula is in particular a word) so you just need to show $Σ^$ is countable. A very useful lemma to remember is that an at most countable union of at most countable sets is countable. Can you see how to use it?

As observed by Jean Abou Samra, every formula is represented by a word on some finite alphabet $A$. Up to a bijection, we may assume that $A = \{0, 1, \dotsm, b-1\}$. Now it suffices to show that $A^*$, the set of all words on the alphabet $A$, is countable. Let $E$ be the set of natural numbers whose representation in base $b$ starts with a $1$. Thus every element of $E$ can be uniquely written in the form $1u$, with $u$ in $A^*$.
As an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $E$ is countable, and the map $1u \to u$ defines a bijection from $E$ to $A^*$. Thus $A^*$ is countable.

Here is a (rough) outline of how a bijection can be created.
You can start by forming a Bijection between $\mathbb N$ and the set of  propositions (zero order logic) using only one variable (will explain later). These consist of expressions like $x, ¬x, x ∨ ¬x$, $x ∧ x$, $¬(x ∧ (x ∨ x))$, etc. There is a context free grammar for such expressions:
$E \rightarrow A ∨ E \text{ } | \text{ } E $
$A \rightarrow A ∧ E \text{ } | \text{ } N $
$N \rightarrow ¬N \text{ } | \text{ } P$
$P \rightarrow (E) \text{ } | \text{ } x$
One way to construct a bijection is to produce a parse tree for each proposition, and label the expressions according to the depth of the parse tree, and some particular precedence order (e.g. and expressions are mapped to lower values first before or expressions).
We can always "lift" a particular bijection $\phi : X \rightarrow \mathbb N$, $\phi(x)=n$ to an injective mapping, say, $\sigma : X \rightarrow \mathbb N$,  $\sigma(x)=2{\phi(x)}+1=2n+1$, giving us "more room" to construct more detailed bijections.
For each $0$-th order proposition, e.g. $x ∧ (x ∨ x)$, we may insert quantifiers anywhere at the beginning of the expression, or at the start of a parthenaized sub-expression. Of course, finitely many quantifiers can be inserted at a particular place, for example, $∀v_0∃v_1 \text{  } x ∧ (∃v_2 \text{  } x ∨ x)$. We may construct a bijective mapping : $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N^i$ where $i$ is the number of places we can insert bounded quantifiers. An ordered tuple of numbers the number of quantifiers we insert at a specific space (left to right). The first number in the sequence is the number of quantifiers whose scope is the entire expression.
For each possible tuple, however, there are now only a finite number of first-order expressions we can create :
Let $P$ be such an expression and $T = (t, t_2, t_3, ... t_p)$ be a particular tuple and denote $t = \sum_{t'\in T} t'$. Suppose $x$ occurs in $P$, $n$ times. Each $x$ can be replaced with a set-membership relation $a \in b$, where $a$ and $b$ are quantified or free variables.  There are $\binom{2n+t-1}t$ ways to map each $a$ and $b$ to a quantified variable.
However, we want to only have one free variable, hence if we choose $k$ variables to be free, and the remaining $2n-k$ to be quantified, we have $\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2n-k+t-1}{t}$ ways to map set-membership variables to quantified/free variables.  Each quantified variable can be an existential, or a universal quantifier, giving us two choices for each quantified variable. The total number of formulas for a particular proposition $P$ and tuple $T$ is
$$2^t\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2n-k+t-1}{t}$$
At this point, we only need to modify our bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N^k$ (for each specific proposition and $p$-tuple) to account for these finite possibilities (e.g. we want to alter $\sigma$ to account for such possibilities, below).
This should (indirectly) show the number of formulas is countable.
$\phi$ is the bijection from the set of propositions to $\mathbb N$
$\gamma_p$ is a bijection from $\mathbb N^p$ to $\mathbb N$
$\sigma(x) = (2*\phi(x)+1)*2^{\alpha(\gamma_p(x))}$
where $p$ is of course (should be) the size of the tuple needed for each proposition $x$, as described above.
